# Google+ Invite - iOS SDK/API - Is there a practical way to invite Google Plus users in a similarly to Facebook invites

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus

Is there a native or somewhat practical way to invite google plus friends w/the G+ iOS SDK/API? Facebook provides this out of the box and one would think this would be available for Google? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit: The Google+ SDK is now deprecated, but you can get similar invite functionality with [Firebase Invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/) which also works with Google contacts.

Absolutely, interactive posts are probably what you need: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share#adding_interactive_posts

You can add a post with a "Join" call to action, which can be setup to deeplink to your mobile application directly, or to go to a URL. Unfortunately on iOS there is no way to prefill the recipient list at this time (you can on Web and Android!), but the user still has the option to choose from any of the circles as part of the share. You can set the prefilled text (which the user has the option of editing).

Interactive posts have 2 components, a "content" link which is generally informational, and a call to action button, which generally is going to be used for taking some action.

```
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];
[shareBuilder setURLToShare:YOUR_CONTENT_LINK];

[shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Try this amazing app with me!"]

[shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"turns-on-app-deeplinks-and-passes-this-value"];

[shareBuilder setCallToActionButtonWithLabel:@"JOIN"
                                        URL:YOUR_JOIN_LINK
                                 deepLinkID:@"turns-on-cta-app-deeplinks"];

[shareBuilder open];
```

Comment: the google plus sdk for ios is deprecated. So answer needs to update.